# How to fill a table with values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have this code that outputs all of the values I need, consisting of each value of `condA` and `CGSorth`.  But I would like them to be placed in a nice table with `condA` and `CGSorth` as column names and each value outputted from the for loop to place in each row of the table. Is this possible in MATLAB?

```
    nr=50; %Number of rows
    nc=10; %Number of columns
for j = 1:10,
    CondNumb=10^j-1;
    A=randn(nr,nc);
    [U,S,V]=svd(A);
    S(S~=0)=linspace(CondNumb,1,min(nr,nc));
    A=U*S*V';

    condA = cond(A)

    [Q1,R1] = cgs(A);

%  Test orthgonality of Q

    I = eye(10);

    CGSorth = norm(Q1'*Q1 - I)
end
```

As per request, I am using my own cgs() function which is defined as follows,

```
function [Q,R] = cgs(A)
% CGS computes the thin QR factorization
% of A using the CGS algorithm
% --------------------------------------
[m,n] = size(A);
Q = A; R = zeros(n);
for k = 1:n
    R(1:k-1,k) = Q(:,1:k-1)'*A(:,k);
    Q(:,k) = A(:,k)- Q(:,1:k-1)*R(1:k-1,k);
    R(k,k) = norm(Q(:,k));
    Q(:,k) = Q(:,k)/R(k,k);
end
end
```

Comment: Are you using `cgs` from MATLAB?  If you are, the `cgs` statement is incomplete.  It requires the right hand side vector `b` as you are trying to solve a linear system of equations using the conjugate gradient method.  Please edit your code to make this runnable.

Comment: @rayryeng no cgs was my own function. I changed it to just say qr() now. The code should run but won't give the appropriate values. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  You can change it back because I didn't know that you were using your own `cgs` function.  You probably want to make that clear in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible.  You can save all of your results in a matrix, convert the matrix into a table and add in the necessary headers.

Firstly, create the matrix where the total number of columns would be 2 where these reflect the number of variables you want to examine per iteration and the number of rows is the same as the number of iterations in your loop.

Once you do this, use [`array2table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html) to convert your matrix into a table, then insert the column names using the `'VariableNames'` option.  The code below is what you have in your post, but with the `% New` comments inserted so you can see where I've added or modified:

```
nr=50; %Number of rows
nc=10; %Number of columns

% New - Results matrix
results = zeros(10, 2);

for j = 1:10,
    CondNumb=10^j-1;
    A=randn(nr,nc);
    [U,S,V]=svd(A);
    S(S~=0)=linspace(CondNumb,1,min(nr,nc));
    A=U*S*V';

    results(j, 1) = cond(A); % New - Add condition number to first column

    [Q1,R1] = cgs(A);

    %  Test orthgonality of Q

    I = eye(10);

    results(j, 2) = norm(Q1'*Q1 - I); % New - Add orthogonality to second column
end

% Create table
T = array2table(results, 'VariableNames', {'condA', 'CGSorth'});

% Display table
disp(T);
```

You'll get something like this once you display it:

```
>> format long g;
>> disp(T);

         condA                CGSorth       
    ________________    ____________________

    9.00000000000001    1.02024117343737e-15
    99.0000000000003    2.61487922829389e-14
    999.000000000017    1.02820433717383e-13
    9999.00000000003    1.08962767582649e-12
    99998.9999998966    1.14443469795116e-11
    999999.000010537    1.36760256617001e-10
    9999998.99939448    2.76938908715533e-09
    99999999.0511774    1.93287185175596e-08
     1000000006.7591    2.22854749762561e-07
    9999999331.44749    1.20332990732236e-06
```

I've also used `format long g` to increase the amount of digits of precision shown.  Also note that these numbers may change slightly per invocation of this script due to the randomized nature of the matrix `A` per iteration (via `randn`).  As an added bonus, you can add row names to this table and show what iteration generated each results:

```
>> T = array2table(results, 'VariableNames', {'condA', 'CGSorth'}, 'RowNames', sprintfc('Iteration %d', 1:10));
>> disp(T)
                         condA                CGSorth       
                    ________________    ____________________

    Iteration 1     9.00000000000001    1.02024117343737e-15
    Iteration 2     99.0000000000003    2.61487922829389e-14
    Iteration 3     999.000000000017    1.02820433717383e-13
    Iteration 4     9999.00000000003    1.08962767582649e-12
    Iteration 5     99998.9999998966    1.14443469795116e-11
    Iteration 6     999999.000010537    1.36760256617001e-10
    Iteration 7     9999998.99939448    2.76938908715533e-09
    Iteration 8     99999999.0511774    1.93287185175596e-08
    Iteration 9      1000000006.7591    2.22854749762561e-07
    Iteration 10    9999999331.44749    1.20332990732236e-06
```

Take note that I used the [undocumented function `sprintfc`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function) to help create a cell array of strings where each cell has the string `Iteration i` where `i` is the iteration number.  The rows require a cell array of strings where each cell is per row so I had to cheat a little bit.